# Can't uninstall Python on Windows (3.4.2)

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I accidentally downloaded Python 3.4.2 a while back but I actually needed Python 2.7, so I deleted the 3.4.2 files and downloaded 2.7 instead. Now I need Python 3, so I tried to download it but I noticed that in the control panel in the Uninstall Programs section it tells me that the 3.4.2 from back then is still on my PC.

Every time I try to uninstall/change/repair/download a newer version I can't and it tells me

> A program required to complete the installation can not be found...

I can not find any remaining files connected to any sort of Python in my PC. My operating system is Windows 10. Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham windows 10

Comment: Did you try downloading  a .msi and just installing with that? https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: I tried now but again the same problem. when I try to install it tells me that a program required could not be run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to reinstall the version you want to delete and then uninstall it afterwards ?

Comment: When you do this, always be aware that you re-created the uninstall information using a fresh install, in particular this may not contain all the necessary info to delete all the files of the previous installation. You can either check the files manually afterwards and/or try to recreate the installation and reinstall absolutely everything you installed before to uninstall. This is most likely to miss less things during uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean `Path` in environment variables [see here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
Just delete the old version path, looks like this: `C:\Python27\;`

Comment: I tried but no help. but mayB I did it wrong. Im not that good in this things.

Comment: Try to use the same .msi file (same version) for uninstalling as was used for installing.